# Is UNSET() compatible with autoload

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, autoload

Using Amazon MWS code config.ini.php to set up classes for MarketplaceWebServices.

This used autoload defintions to create variables using new.

As we are using different authorization credentials for different Amazon sites I have needed to change the details beteen sites.

The use of UNSET()

```
unset($service);
```

before

```
$service = new MarketplaceWebService_Client(
     $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
     $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, 
     $config,
     APPLICATION_NAME,
     APPLICATION_VERSION
);
```

results in $service not being an object on being called the second time.

Which brings me to the question "Is UNSET() compatible with autoload ?"

Comment: Can you show the full code and the exact line where you get the error please?

Answer (score 1):

`unset()` has nothing to do with autoloading, and will not interfer with it. Once the class is loaded using an autoloader, `unset()`ing an instance will not cause it to not be available any longer.

If that were the case, you'd get an error about `MarketplaceWebService_Client` not being an avaliable class.

Comment: the first time called unset($service) unsets a not set variable.

Comment: The first time. 
1. Called unset($service) unsets a declared global variable that has had no rhs value assigned. 

2. Then the call to new for a non defined class calls the autoload to define the classs and create an instance as $service.
This instance is used and works as per normal.

On sunsequent calls.
1. Variable $service is unset. 

2. The call to `Service = new` doesn't create an instance of `MarketplaceWebService_Client` and causes the program to abend with exception message attempt to use $-service-> on a non object.

Comment: stackoverflow strips comment from spaced and useful info into a block of Lorem ipsum

Comment: Is it possible that instance of `MarketplaceWebService_Client` is doing something to the `$config` or keys that keeps it from being used further?

Answer (score 0):

> Is UNSET() compatible with autoload ?

Yes. (Simple question, simple answer.)

Comment: Your conclusion invalidates my evidence, where is your contra evidence ?

Comment: Which *evidence*? You didn't post any code example to reproduce the esoteric looking description. And just that it's noted: I never experience any "incompatibility". Unset just unsets a variable (or removes a reference/alias) (just for the log).

Answer (score 0):

Running the following demonstrates that unset should work OK with autoload.
The test class didn't use __contruct().
So it looks like something in `MarketplaceWebService_Client` MWS is upsetting the apple cart.

```
$shipping_calc = new shipping_calc();
echo "ORIG \$shipping_calc=" . print_r($shipping_calc, true);

unset($shipping_calc);
echo "UNSET() \$shipping_calc=" . print_r($shipping_calc, true);

$shipping_calc = new shipping_calc();
echo "NEW \$shipping_calc=" . print_r($shipping_calc, true);
```